# Calculate percentage of parcel area covered by wetland

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Still a little new to Postgis. I'm trying to calculate the percentage of a wetland layer that intersects with a parcel layer. The desire is to eventually add "percent_wetland" to the parcel layer, but I'm having trouble working out the basic query. Both layers are polygons and have the same EPSG. My query below returns a value of ~300 whereas the correct value should be about 35(%).

```
SELECT (sum(st_area(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom))/st_area(b.geom)))*100 percent_area, b.id

from hydrology.wetland a, boundaries.parcels as b

WHERE b.id=9801

GROUP BY b.id;
```

How does one calculate the percentage of area that intersects between two polygon layers?

Answer (score 2):

The only tricky bits are keeping in mind that:

- It's possible a single parcel could intersect more than one wetland polygon. To deal with this, we sum up the areas of all intersections per parcel.
- It's possible a parcel could intersect *no* wetland polygons. To deal with this, we left join the original table to the result of the intersection, so we still have one record per parcel.

So the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE parcels_with_wl_area AS
WITH parcel_wetland_area AS (
  SELECT p.id, Sum(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(wl.geom, p.geom))) AS wetland_area
  FROM wetlands wl
  JOIN parcels p
  ON ST_Intersects(wl.geom, p.geom)
  GROUP BY p.id
)
SELECT p.*, 
  CASE 
    WHEN pwa.wetland_area IS NULL 
    THEN 0.0 
    ELSE pwa.wetland_area 
  END AS wetland_area,
  CASE 
    WHEN pwa.wetland_area IS NULL 
    THEN 0
    ELSE round(100 * pwa.wetland_area / ST_Area(p.geom))
  END AS wetland_pct
FROM parcels p
LEFT JOIN parcel_wetland_area pwa
ON p.id = pwa.id
```

The case statement is needed to convert the left join nulls into zeroes. Now you have wetland areas, and you can get a percentage just by dividing by the ST_Area() of the parcel geometry.

Comment: Works perfectly! Brilliant! Thanks @Paul for your help. I was very impressed that it executed in only 1.1 sec. I was sorta, kinda on the right track... :) One followup question: this query produces the total area (in meters), but what if I want the percentage of the total parcel area covered with wetland? The parcel area is currently in a field called "area_sqm". Can I compute this in the main SELECT statement (e.g. SELECT p.*, CASE..., wetland_area/parcels.area_sqm*100)?

Comment: I answered my own followup question... adding wetland_area/p.area_sqm*100 AS perc_wetland works. Thanks again, @Paul.

Comment: You can add % inline, as I've edited the example, or just calculate it in subsequent queries when you read the new table.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks again! I didn't realize you added both pct and area in your updated query. All is good.